# "Вручную приклеить" одну строку (0, 0) к результатам SELECT

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть запрос:

```
SELECT ... as X, ... as Y FROM table WHERE ... ORDER BY ... ASC
```

Мне нужно, чтобы в начале результата, выданного по этому запросу, появилась еще одна строка: `X=0, Y=0`

Как такое сделать?

Answer (score 2):

```
    SELECT ... as X, ... as Y 
    FROM table 
    WHERE ... 
UNION ALL 
    SELECT 0, 0 
ORDER BY ... ASC
```

Comment: супер! спасибо большое!